# Hibernate / JPA: Is it possible to Override @Id field?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is there a method to reassign the `@Id` in child entity after it was assigned to some field in the parent entity

For example:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class Parent implements Serializable {

  @Id
  protected Integer parentId;

  public Integer getId() {
    return parentId;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = parentId;
  }
}


@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Child extends Parent implements Serializable {

  /*
   What should be added to this entity to re assign the @Id to a new field and 
   make the parentId field just an ordianry field in the Child, not the entity Id
  */
  @Id
  private Long childId;

}
```

I have tried to use [`@AttributeOverride`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html), but all it could provide is to rename the id column name.

Comment: I think it is not possible. How should it then be mapped to RDB? It is for sure not possible for "Single table per hierarchy" and "Table per subclass". Why do you need that feature? (Btw.: Why does your Child subclass Parent?)

Comment: @isnot2bad I have a Generic entity that wrap id, version, and some other fields that are shared between a lot of entities. and the application is already built with the Generic Entity in mind. but for some new entities that are sharing the same fields except for the Id field type and name. However they still keep the old Id column but as an ordinary field

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like a design problem.

The proper way to achieve this is probably to define another class : `@MappedSuperclass GenericEntity` with all attributes of `Parent` except the `parentId` :

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class GenericEntity implements Serializable {
     ... all your common attributes without parentId
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Parent extends GenericEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    protected Integer parentId;

    public Integer getId() {
        return parentId;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = parentId;
    }

    //nothing more in this class
}

@Entity
public class Child extends GenericEntity implements Serializable {

   @Id
   private Long childId;

   private Integer parentId; //if you need it

   ...
}
```

---

An alternative experimental solution can be to hide the `parentId` field in the `Child` class.

Disclaimer : I don't recommend this approach, and I'm not sure it will work !

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Child extends GenericEntity implements Serializable {

   @Id
   private Long childId;

   private Integer parentId;

   ...
}
```

Comment: Your second solution will add two Ids for the Child, an exception was thrown in other entities referencing the child entities indicating that I should assign TWO columns for the foreign key

Comment: And for the first solution it will cause Refactoring in a lot of entities. Anyway thanks and upvote for the effort, but this doesn't solve my main question if it is possible to reassign the Id or not?

Answer (score 0):

you can override annotation metadata by xml:
for hibernate see e.g. [this post](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/xml-overriding.html)

for general JPA see e.g. [this post](http://www.bigdev.org/2012/01/overwriting-jpa-annotations-with-orm-xml/)